# How to replace .bind() and .unbind() in script that appends and adds classes?

Tags: jquery

I have this older script which I need to revise to make it work with a load more feature. But I'm running into an issue with replacing .bind() and .unbind(). The script as it stands adds classes in a few places and then removes those classes when a certain element is clicked and unclicked.

When I tried replacing .bind() with .on() and .unbind() with.off() the script fails. Any thoughts?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //alert('bbbb')
  // cache the floating element
  var goToTop = $(".sendids");
  // bind to the window's scroll event to move the element with the user
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    goToTop.stop().animate({
      "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
    }, "slow");
  });
  $(".add-job").bind("click", function(e) {
    temp = "#s" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    //alert('show id: ' + temp);
    $(this).toggleClass("check");
    if ($(temp).length != 0) {
      // remove ID from selected ID list
      $("div#" + temp).remove();
      temp = null;
      if ($("#selectedids").children().size() == 0) {
        $(".sendids").removeClass("hover");
        $(".sendids-hor").removeClass("hover");
      }
    } else {
      // add ID to selected ID list
      $("#selectedids").append('<div id="' + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + '"></div>');
      $(".sendids").addClass("hover");
      $(".sendids-hor").addClass("hover");
    }

    if ($("#selectedids").children().size() > 0) {
      //alert('aaaaaa');

      $(".sendids,.sendids-hor").bind("click", function() {
        var allids = '';
        var clickeditem = $(this);
        $("#selectedids").contents().each(function(index) {
          if (index > 0) {
            allids += ",";
          }
          allids += $(this).attr("id");
        });
        if ($("#workshops").has(clickeditem).length > 0) {
          window.location = "/mail-workshop-ids?ids=" + allids;
        } else {
          //send selected IDs to form page;
          window.location = "localhost/job-applicant-information-request?ids=" + allids;
        }
      });
    } else {
      //alert('bbbb')
      $(".sendids").unbind("click");
    }
  });
});
```

I'm also try to make this work with a document wide .on("click") event but first I need to replace the .bind and .unbind

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running? .on was added in 1.7.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details. Include the version and any errors that are shown or seen in Console. Please also consider providing a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry Forgot that. It's running on a wordpress site which of course is loading  jQuery v1.12.4  and  jQuery v3.2.1. Yes the site is a mess that I inherited and need to clean up.

Comment: Fails how exactly? Do you get console errors?

Comment: In its current form it works fine. But it is used on a page which loads up about 40+ postings which the user is then supposed to choose from in terms of job interests. Obviously all these database calls slow down the page load. So I was trying to add an ajax load more script so that only 10 posts load on to the page.  But where there error come in is when I try to change any instance of .bind to .on that works fine but when changing .unbind to .off() the script fails to remove the classes that where added in the bind section of the script.

Comment: Should work fine switching `bind()` with `on()`...under the hood `bind()` just calls `on()`

Comment: Where it really fails is when I add an ajax based load more script. This script doesn't work at all on the items that are added by ajax. I realized that I might need to revise this with and .on function but not sure where.

Comment: That's  a completely different issue . You would need to use event delegation signature for it to work on elements that don't exist at run time   [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks Charlie! That points me in the right direction!